# How to convert Bitmap to Image

Tags: c#, winforms, gdi+

I am making a median filter, the problem is manipulating pixes are only possible in `Bitmap`. Later I want to show the result in a `PictureBox` which uses `Image`. I can't figure out a way to to solve this...Only thing I can think of is using a `Stream` but no idea how. Help will be appriciated~

```
private void toolStripPerformMedian_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var filtered = Filters.MedianFilter(new Bitmap(_activeImageFile), 3);
    var n = Image.FromStream() //How to do this?
}
```

Comment: A Bitmap **is** an Image; you can just assign the Bitmap to the Image property of the PictureBox.

Comment: @DJKRAZE, the question you mention is completely unrelated... The OP is using GDI, not WPF

Comment: This link will help Sorry Thomas.. http://www.wischik.com/lu/programmer/1bpp.html

Answer (score 94, accepted):

A [`Bitmap`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.bitmap.aspx) is an `Image`. It inherits from the `Image` class.

[From MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.bitmap.aspx):

```
[SerializableAttribute]
[ComVisibleAttribute(true)]
public sealed class Bitmap : Image
```

Comment: Not to be confused with BitmapImage.

Answer (score 3):

This is what has worked for me:

```
var codeBitmap = new Bitmap(your_info);
Image image = (Image)codeBitmap;
```

Comment: with out context of which namespace this Image class is being pulled in from, it's a bit confusing. As others have said Bitmap inherits from Image, so any property or argument that excepts image, can take a bitmap, there is no need for this cast. If it is the WIndows.Control.Image and then this won't work and neither will the code above

Comment: @Dave I saw a lot of answers (about converting bitmap to image) and tried many code snippets but none of them, except the one in my answer, worked.

Comment: Image image = new Bitmap(your_info); //works all by itself.

Answer (score 1):

Check up the namespaces.
`System.Drawing.Image` compatible with bitmap, `System.Window.Control.Image` - not!